# How to have multiple position state for viewcontroller's views?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, storyboard

The problem I'm trying to solve is this: I have a `DetailViewController` that displays the data for my Model with `UIImageView`'s, `UITextFields`'s, etc.

If the user taps a button, those `DetailViewController`'s views move to different positions and start to be editable. When editable, if the user taps one of the `UITextField` (just one of them is special) the `UITextField` moves to the top of the screen and a `UITableView` appears to autocomplete it (just like when you type something on google).

The user can also tap the same button to go back to the display state (where nothing is editable).

So basically I have some views in a `ViewController` with 3 possible state: `DisplayState`, `EditingState`, `EditingWithFocusOnSpecialTextFieldsState`.

I'd like to have all those positioning state described by `NSLayoutConstraints`, and, if possible, just in the storyboard.

One thing I could do is this [Animate to a storyboard state / position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903571/animate-to-a-storyboard-state-position), but this involves writing every constraint for each state in code, therefore I couldn't visualize them really well in storyboard while developing (Also, writing constraints in code is a lot less maintainable than in storyboard).

What I would like is something like creating 3 different XIBs, for example, or different copies of my `DetailViewController` in storyboard with the 3 different positions for each of the subviews, and then animate between them.

If it makes any difference, I'm always using the latest iOS version (iOS 8 right now) and Swift.
I do know Objective-C very well too if you don't want to answer in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this with 3 different views, and get the result you want (at least no straight forward way). One approach would be to make 3 constraints (one for each state) to any one edge of the superview that you need to adjust for each view (in addition to any other constraints you need that you're not going to modify). One would have a high priority (I'm using 900, it can't be 1000), and the other 2 would have a lower priority (499 in my example). When you switch states, you change which of the 3 has the high priority. This does involve making a lot of constraints, and I found that the easiest way to implement the switching in code was to give the constraints identifiers in IB (which you do in the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" section of the Identity Inspector). This approach means I don't have to make IBOutlets for all those constraints. Here is an example with two views in the storyboard,

[image]

You can see the text field has 3 constraints to the top, and the image view has 3 centerY constraints (though you can't see that there are 3). Each constraint (in the groups of 3) has its identifier set to "display", "edit", or "focus". I give the one that's called "display" the priority of 900, and the other 2 get 499 (because I want the view to start in display mode). In this test app, I'm using 3 buttons to change the state, though, of course, you could use other means to accomplish that. Here is the code I use to switch the priorities,

```
enum EditState: String {
    case Display = "display" // these strings are the same as the ones assigned to the identifier property of the constraints in IB (in "user defined runtime attributes")
    case Editing = "edit"
    case EditWithFocus = "focus"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    func updatEditingState(state: EditState) {
        var constraintsArray = self.view.constraints() as [NSLayoutConstraint]
        constraintsArray += self.imageView.constraints() as [NSLayoutConstraint]

        for con in constraintsArray {
            if let name = con.identifier? {
                if name == "display" || name == "edit" || name == "focus" {
                    con.priority = (name == state.rawValue) ? 900 : 499
                }
            }
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}
}


    @IBAction func EnterEditingState(sender: UIButton) {
        updatEditingState(EditState.Editing)
    }


    @IBAction func enterDisplayStatus(sender: UIButton) {
        updatEditingState(EditState.Display)
    }


    @IBAction func enterFocusStatus(sender: UIButton) {
        updatEditingState(EditState.EditWithFocus)
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't implemented that yet, but that idea is awesome! I'll accept your answer for sure if this works as expected =)

Comment: What would you do if one of the constraints (just one) should be equal for 2 states? should I still create 3 constraints (with 2 having the same constant) or create a different identifier like "Display,Editing" and parsing that in the VC?

Comment: another question, that will only get the constraints from the main view right? It won't work if I have a height constraint that changes for the 3 states

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, for the first question, I would still create 3 with 2 having the same constant. A height constraint will work, but since that constraint is owned by that view (not self.view), you would have to combine the arrays of constraints from self.view, and any other view that has size constraints (you also need an IBOutlet for any of those views). Also, the low value for the constraint has to be under 500 (499 works). I edited the code to my answer. So, in my example, the image view changes position and height for each state.

Comment: I ended up traversing the entire view tree and looking at every constraint for every subview. Why does it need to be 499? I haven't finished implementing everything, but it seems to be working with 500. Also, stupid (maybe non-related) question, how do I make the height equal de origin.x of the view (i.e. leave a square space to the left side of the view)?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, I'm not sure why it needs to be less than 500 -- I noticed that 500 seemed to work in code, but it gave me red warnings in IB when I added a second height constraint with a 500 priority. Changing it to 499 got rid of the warnings. I'm not sure if you can relate a height to an origin.X. Are you trying to leave a space that's the same size as the view?

Comment: Weird, the two 500 constraints didn't give me a warning. Yes, I am, but this view changes size, and the second view should not change size with it, but always leave that square space.